# In Batch Normalisation, are $\hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\sigma}$ the mean and stdev of the original mini-batch or of the input into the current layer?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, batch-normalization

In Batch Normalisation, are the sample mean and standard deviation we normalise by the mean/sd of the original data put into the network, or of the inputs in the layer we are currently BN'ing over?

For instance, suppose I have a mini-batch size of 2 which contains $\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2$. Suppose now we are at the $k$th layer and the outputs from the previous layer are $\tilde{\textbf{x}}_1,\tilde{\textbf{x}}_2$. When we perform batch norm at this layer would be subtract the sample mean of $\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2$ or of $\tilde{\textbf{x}}_1,\tilde{\textbf{x}}_2$?

My intuition tells me that it must be the mean,sd of $\tilde{\textbf{x}}_1,\tilde{\textbf{x}}_2$ otherwise I don't think it would be normalised to have 0 mean and sd of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. We will be normalizing the inputs of the layer under consideration (just right before applying the activation function).

So, if this layer receives an input $\mathrm{x}=\left(x^{(1)} \ldots x^{(d)}\right)$, the formula for normalizing the $k^{th}$ dimension of $\mathrm{x}$ would look as follows:
$$\widehat{x}^{(k)}=\frac{x^{(k)}-\mathrm{E}\left[x^{(k)}\right]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left[x^{(k)}\right]}}$$

Note that in practice a constant $\epsilon$ is also added under the square root in the denominator to ensure stability.

Source: The original [Batch Normalization paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) (Section 3).

Andrew Ng's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em6dfRxYkYU) on this topic might also be useful for illustration.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! it was actually the original paper I read that confused me.

Comment: Right. There are a few locations in the text where they define it in an explicit manner (like in the abstract or when they define $x$ ). In some places, they may also refer to the process as “normalizing the activations”.